# How to script Blender drag and drop texture image replacement

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, objects, image

I am trying to work up a script that takes an object that already has an image texture, and replaces the image that is in the texture with an image that is dragged into Blender from my computer. In short, I want to make it so that Blender I can drag and drop an image onto a textured object such as a plane, and have the image that I choose replace the image used in the texture.

Now, I'm not sure where to start - but I do know that I need to know how to call the drag/drop function in Blenders python toolset. Though I can't find any 'drag and drop' python references.

I've seen this done in the 'drag and drop environments' addon by Blendersensei, as well as some of Andrew Price's addons such as pro lighting skies, and pro lighting.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!